# Persistent checkbox cannot alter using hook_form_alter

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to alter a checked checkbox using hook_form_alter with this:

```
$form['foo']['#attributes'] = array();
```

and/or

```
$form['foo']['#default_value'] = '0';
```

Basically the current output of the form is this:

```
[foo] => array (
   [#type] => [checkbox]
   [#attributes] => array (
       [checked] => [checked]
      )
)
```

This is a checkbox that is checked by default. Now I want to uncheck the box and save it as that.

I managed to uncheck the box by default but that value does not save at all. Form is still being submitted with the checkbox checked.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this $form['foo']['#default_value'] = array('0');

The default value for checkbox is always an array of values. Remember its value and not the string displayed on the form.